# Jupyter notebook permission denied, unable to save

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I am having permission denied for Jupyter notebook running on Ubuntu, AWS E2 instance. Below is the image for the error

[image: Permission error 403 error]

[image: Details of my file in ubuntu]

I have tried to use other browser, reinstall it and clear cache. None of it works.

Answer (score 0):

If your notebook is configured with some auth code (generated by notebook by default), and you've cleared your cache, and cookies, you will get the screen similar to below:
[image: Notebook Authentication]

Here you can use the token shown in terminal, while running the notebook, the log will be similar to the below:

```
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/ubuntu/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-19740-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://ip-123-1-1-123:8888/?token=abcdefghijl
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=abcdefghijl
```

and if you want to run notebook without authentication you can run the below command:

```
jupyter notebook --ip='0.0.0.0' --NotebookApp.token='' --NotebookApp.password=''
```

Also try creating a new notebook, instead of accessing the Test.ipynb again, so that you can figure out if the issue is from the specific file or whole server.

Comment: I have tried but not working. The problem is at the server

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is i don't have the permission to overwrite the file. First of all, i create the file at /home/ubuntu, which I don't have permission of. So i create a folder to store the file inside it. Other than that, i also done quite a lot modifications including adding the inbound rules and the permissions, i think some of it did help. I list out some of the website i think is very useful in tackling this issue:

1. [PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: Cannot open Jupyter on Browser despite running correctly on AWS EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55871531/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-cannot-open-jupyter-on-browser-de)
2. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097180/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-when-accessing-to-aws-ec2#:~:text=Make%20sure%20you%20type%20https,with%20version%2070%20or%20newer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097180/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-when-accessing-to-aws-ec2#:%7E:text=Make%20sure%20you%20type%20https,with%20version%2070%20or%20newer).